# How to get the "pen" snap work?

Tags: snap

OS: Openbox session of Lubuntu 16.04

`snap find | grep -E '^pen` comes up with this:

> pen                        1.0.0                      stephen-stewart-blah  -      pen is a Markdown previewer written in JavaScript, aiming to just work.

So I ran `sudo snap install pen`. But, after that, running `pen` in a terminal just shows

```
listening 6060 ...
```

with the terminal's cursor on the next line. Nothing else happens.

`ps -aux | grep pen` shows

```
$ ps -aux | grep pen  
dkbos     8694  0.0  0.4 186612 17028 ?        Ss   22:13   0:00 /usr/bin/openbox --startup /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openbox-autostart OPENBOX  
dkbos     8750  0.0  0.0  11232   332 ?        Ss   22:13   0:00 /usr/bin/ssh-agent /usr/bin/dbus-launch --exit-with-session /usr/bin/im-launch /usr/bin/openbox-session  
dkbos     8753  0.0  0.0  43600   372 ?        S    22:13   0:00 /usr/bin/dbus-launch --exit-with-session /usr/bin/im-launch /usr/bin/openbox-session  
dkbos     9668  0.0  0.0   4508   704 pts/0    S+   22:21   0:00 /bin/sh /snap/bin/pen  
dkbos     9669  1.0  1.3 917144 52780 pts/0    Sl+  22:21   0:00 node /snap/pen/1/bin/pen  
dkbos     9712  0.0  0.0  14224   948 pts/1    S+   22:23   0:00 grep pen
```

Where the third-last and second-last lines are relevant.

Is it possible that this snap doesn't work on my system but requires Unity? Where can I read more about `pen`? There's no manual entry for `pen`.

Answer (score 1):

From what it's printing it sounds like it's listening on port 6060. Try visiting http://localhost:6060 and see what happens.

Note that you know it doesn't require unity7 by looking at the interfaces it's using:

```
$ snap interfaces
<snip>
:network             -
:network-bind        pen
:network-control     -
<snip>
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. How do I visit http://localhost:6060? I thought this would have something to allow me to preview my markdown files (as per the description). Does `pen` work for you to view markdown files?